# for each natural number n, the numbers $4^{4n + 2} + 3^{n + 2}$ and $3^{n + 2}$ are coprime.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I am trying to check that, for each natural number n, the numbers $\ 4^{4n + 2} + 3^{n + 2}$ and $\ 3^{n + 2}$ are coprime.

This tells me that gcd(a,b)=1. Now I need to see if applies to all n

I am not sure if this the right way and how to do it $\ dn = gcd(4^{4n + 2} + 3^{n + 2}, 3^{n + 2})$

I would appreciate if anyone could help me to understand the right way to do it.

Thanks

Roberto

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. $\gcd(4^{4n+2}+3^{n+2},3^{n+2})=\gcd(4^{4n+2},3^{n+2})=1$ for $n>0$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Set $ a=4^{4n + 2}$ and $b= 3^{n + 2}$ and use 
$\gcd(a+b,b)=\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: and that $4^{4n+2}=2^{8n+4}$ which does not have any common factor with $3^{\cdots}$

Comment: So it is not possible to factorize. To prove that this applies to all n should I use induction? or because a=even and b=odd then they are coprime?

Comment: @Robert:  just because $a$ is even and $b$ is odd doesn’t mean gcd($a,b)=1$, but if $a$ is a power of $4$ (i.e., $2$) and $b$ is a power of $3$ then it’s true